# Mysql 5.7 json datatype, query with activerecord in Rails 5

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, mysql-5.7

I am making an application with Rails 5 rc1.
Rails 5 support mysql 5.7 json datatype.

```
add_column :organizations, :external, :json
```

Suppose the value in this column is as follows:

```
+---------------------------+
| external                  |
+---------------------------+
| {"id": 10, "type": "mos"} |
+---------------------------+
```

To search a particular "id" and "type" in external column, I use the following query in mysql:

```
select external from organizations where JSON_CONTAINS(external,'{"id": 10, "type": "mos"}') ;
```

Now, I want to know, how to make the same query using rails.
The following doesn't work:

```
Organization.where("JSON_CONTAINS(external,'{"id": 10, "type": "mos"}')")
```

Note: I cannot remove quotes around the json text as it is part of the query.

Answer (score 17):

You can still leverage ActiveRecord's where method and bind variables without resorting to find_by_sql.

```
Organization.where("external->'$.id' = :id and external->'$.type' = :type", id: 10, type: "mos")
```

Comment: This is only applicable for postgresql and not for mysql.

Comment: Works for me in Rails 5.1 and Mysql 5.7

Comment: Does not work on MariaDB 10.4, but JSON_EXTRACT() does.

Comment: Still a valid answer with MySQL 8 and Rails 6

Answer (score 7):

With MYSQL you can use `JSON_EXTRACT` to pull values from a JSON object stored in a field.  In your case, try using...

```
Organization.where("JSON_EXTRACT(external, '$.id') = 10 AND JSON_EXTRACT(external, '$.type') = 'mos'")
```

and just for kicks, in pseudo code...

```
<Class>.where("JSON_EXTRACT(<column_header>, '$.<object key>') <comparison operator> <object value>")
```

This should get the job done, although there may be a prettier way to write it :)

Comment: I like this more because it works both on MySQL and MariaDB.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
id_field = '$."id"'
type_field = '$."type"'    
Organization.where("JSON_UNQUOTE(json_extract(external, '#{id_field}')) = ? AND JSON_UNQUOTE(json_extract(external, '#{type_field}')) = ?", 10, "mos")
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any solution through activerecord as of now. An alternative way to query is as follows:

```
type = "mos"
id = 10

organization = Organization.find_by_sql(["select * from organizations where JSON_CONTAINS(external_ref ,'{\"id\": ?, \"type\": \"#{ActiveRecord::Base::sanitize(type).remove("'")}\"}')", id]).first
```

Once there is a solution with activerecord query interface, I will update.